# Django using generic views, "POST /''/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0, Method Not Allowed (POST)

Tags: python, django

Trying to define Create, Edit and list page for each model I have, after using the Generic view in Django UpdateView and CreateView. after save when forwarding to the listview an HTTP ERROR 405 appears without saving any data.

I am using Django UpdateView for update form, CreateView for add and SingleTableView for the list.

Models.py

```
  class PartnerOrganization(TimeStampedModel):

        name = models.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            unique=True,
            verbose_name=_('Name'))

        coordinator = models.ForeignKey(
            Coordinator,
            blank=False, null=True,
            related_name='+',
            verbose_name=_('Coordinator')
        )

        land_phone_number = models.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            blank=True, null=True,
            verbose_name=_('Partner land phone number')
        )
        fax_number = models.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            blank=True, null=True,
            verbose_name=_('Partner fax number')
        )
        email = models.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            blank=True, null=True,
            verbose_name=_('Partner email')
        )

        owner = models.ForeignKey(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            blank=False, null=True,
            related_name='+',
            verbose_name=_('Created by')
        )


        class Meta:
            ordering = ['name']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("learningcenters:teacher_list")
```

In Views.py

```
class ListingPartnerView(LoginRequiredMixin,
                         GroupRequiredMixin,
                         FilterView,
                         ExportMixin,
                         SingleTableView,
                         RequestConfig):
    table_class = PartnerTable
    model = PartnerOrganization
    template_name = 'learningcenters/partner/list.html'
    table = BootstrapTable(PartnerOrganization.objects.all(), order_by='id')
    # filterset_class = TeacherFilter
    group_required = [u"UNICEF"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        force_default_language(self.request)
        if self.request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['UNICEF']).exists():
            return PartnerOrganization.objects.all()



class AddPartnerView(LoginRequiredMixin,
                     GroupRequiredMixin,
                     CreateView):
    template_name = 'bootstrap4/common_form.html'
    form_class = PartnerForm
    queryset = PartnerOrganization.objects.all()
    # success_url = '/learningcenters/teacher/list/'
    group_required = [u"UNICEF"]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # return reverse("learningcenters:teacher_update", kwargs={"pk": self.id})
        return reverse("learningcenters:partner_list")


    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        form.save(self.request)
        return super(AddPartnerView, self).form_valid(form)


class UpdatePartnerView(LoginRequiredMixin,
                        GroupRequiredMixin,
                        UpdateView):
    template_name = 'bootstrap4/common_form.html'
    form_class = PartnerForm
    queryset = PartnerOrganization.objects.all()
    # success_url = '/learningcenters/teacher/list/'
    group_required = [u"UNICEF"]

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        return get_object_or_404(PartnerOrganization, id=id_)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("learningcenters:partner_list")


    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        form.save(self.request)
        return super(UpdatePartnerView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Tables.py

```
class PartnerTable(tables.Table):

    edit_column = tables.TemplateColumn(verbose_name=_('Edit partner'), orderable=False,
                                        template_name='learningcenters/partner/edit_column.html',
                                         attrs={'url': '/learningcenters/partner/update/'})
    # delete_column = tables.TemplateColumn(verbose_name=_('Delete learning center'), orderable=False,
    #                                       template_name='learningcenters/delete_column.html',
    #                                       attrs={'url': '/api/learningcenters/'})

    # edit = tables.LinkColumn('learningcenters:edit', text='Edit', args=[A('pk')])

    class Meta:
        model = PartnerOrganization
        template = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
        fields = (
            'edit_column',
            # 'delete_column',
            'name',
            'email',
            'land_phone_number',
            'fax_number',
        )
```

Forms.py

```
class PartnerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Partner name"),
        widget=forms.TextInput, required=True
    )

    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=_('Partner email'),
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Format: partner@email.com'})
    )
    land_phone_number = forms.RegexField(
        label=_('Partner land phone number'),
        regex=r'^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}$',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Format: 00-00000'})
    )
    fax_number = forms.RegexField(
        label=_('Partner fax number'),
        regex=r'^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}$',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Format: 00-00000'})
    )

    coordinator_name = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Coordinator name"),
        widget=forms.TextInput, required=True
    )

    coordinator_email = forms.EmailField(
        label=_('Coordinator email'),
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Format: partner@email.com'})
    )
    coordinator_land_phone_number = forms.RegexField(
        label=_('Coordinator land phone number'),
        regex=r'^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}$',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Format: 00-00000'})
    )
    coordinator_fax_number = forms.RegexField(
        label=_('Coordinator fax number'),
        regex=r'^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}$',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Format: 00-00000'})
    )


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PartnerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True
        self.helper.form_action = reverse('learningcenters:partner_list', kwargs={})

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                None,
                Div(
                    HTML('<h4 id="alternatives-to-hidden-labels">' + _('Basic Info') + '</h4>')
                ),
                Div(
                    HTML('<span class="badge badge-default">1</span>'),
                    Div('name', css_class='col-md-3'),
                ),

                css_class='bd-callout bd-callout-primary'
            ),

            Fieldset(
                None,
                Div(
                    HTML('<h4 id="alternatives-to-hidden-labels">' + _('Partner Contact') + '</h4>')
                ),
                Div(
                    HTML('<span class="badge badge-default">2</span>'),
                    Div('land_phone_number', css_class='col-md-3'),
                    HTML('<span class="badge badge-default">3</span>'),
                    Div('fax_number', css_class='col-md-3'),
                    HTML('<span class="badge badge-default">4</span>'),
                    Div('email', css_class='col-md-3'),
                    css_class='row',
                ),

                css_class='bd-callout bd-callout-primary'
            ),

            Fieldset(
                None,
                Div(
                    HTML('<h4 id="alternatives-to-hidden-labels">' + _('Coordinator Contact') + '</h4>')
                ),
                Div(
                    HTML('<span class="badge badge-default">5</span>'),
                    Div('coordinator_name', css_class='col-md-3'),
                    css_class='row',
                ),
                Div(
                    HTML('<span class="badge badge-default">6</span>'),
                    Div('coordinator_email', css_class='col-md-3'),
                    HTML('<span class="badge badge-default">7</span>'),
                    Div('coordinator_land_phone_number', css_class='col-md-3'),
                    HTML('<span class="badge badge-default">8</span>'),
                    Div('coordinator_fax_number', css_class='col-md-3'),
                    css_class='row',
                ),

                css_class='bd-callout bd-callout-primary'
            ),

            FormActions(
                Submit('save', _('Save'), css_class='child_data'),
                Submit('save_add_another', _('Save and add another'), css_class='child_data'),
                # Submit('save_continue_editing', _('Save and continue editing')),
                HTML('<a class="btn btn-info cancel-button" href="/learningcenters/partner/list/" translation="' +
                     _('Are you sure you want to cancel?') + '">' + _('Back to list') + '</a>'),
            )
        )



    class Meta:
        model = PartnerOrganization
        fields = (
            'name',
            'email',
            'land_phone_number',
            'fax_number',
            'coordinator_name',
            'coordinator_email',
            'coordinator_land_phone_number',
            'coordinator_fax_number',
            # 'bln_round',
            # 'rs_round',
            # 'cbece_round',
        )
        initial_fields = fields
        widgets = {}

    class Media:
        js = ()
```

urls.py

```
url(
        regex=r'partner/list/$',
        view=views.ListingPartnerView.as_view(),
        name='partner_list'
    ),

    url(
        regex=r'^partner/add/$',
        view=views.AddPartnerView.as_view(),
        name='partner_add'
    ),

    url(
        regex=r'^partner/update/(?P<pk>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
        view=views.UpdatePartnerView.as_view(),
        name='partner_update'
    ),
```

HTTP ERROR 405
Method Not Allowed (POST): /learningcenters/partner/list/

Comment: Well your ListingPartnerView does not support POST. Why are you trying to post to it? What would that even do?

Comment: You probably want to make a POST request to your `partner/add` endpoint?